# GroovyTemplate of test runner throws exceptions and won't show error detail

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

Sometimes when a scalatest fails, Play test framework does not report the cause of the failure, instead I see the following. Any ideas why?
Reporter completed abruptly with an exception after receiving event:

```
TestFailed(org.scalatest.events.Ordinal@6db,java.util.NoSuchElementException,AsgUpdateActorTest,Some(com.netflix.tachyon.nac.AsgUpdateActorTest),parse xml,Some(java.util.NoSuchElementException),Some(42),None,Some(<function7>),None,play-thread-1,1324496590792).
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at play.test.TestEngine$TestResults.add(TestEngine.java:191)
    at org.scalatest.tools.PlayReporter.apply(ScalaTestRunner.scala:122)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:152)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:151)
    at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foreach(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:61)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:45)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:151)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:101)
    at scala.actors.Actor$class.receive(Actor.scala:524)
    at scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1.receive(Actor.scala:134)
    at scala.actors.Actor$.receive(Actor.scala:189)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:101)
    at org.scalatest.DispatchReporter$$anonfun$1.apply(DispatchReporter.scala:50)
    at scala.Function0$class.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:39)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:17)
    at scala.actors.Actor$$anon$1.act(Actor.scala:135)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
    at scala.actors.Reactor$$anonfun$dostart$1.apply(Reactor.scala:222)
    at scala.actors.ReactorTask.run(ReactorTask.scala:36)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$AdaptedRunnable.exec(ForkJoinPool.java:611)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.quietlyExec(ForkJoinTask.java:422)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.mainLoop(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:340)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:325)
11:43:11,038 ERROR ~ 

@68nef9k71
Cannot ouput XML unit output

Template execution error (In {module:testrunner}/app/views/TestRunner/results-xunit.xml around line 23)
Execution error occured in template {module:testrunner}/app/views/TestRunner/results-xunit.xml. Exception raised was NullPointerException : Cannot invoke method escapeXml() on null object.

play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: Cannot invoke method escapeXml() on null object
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:86)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
    at controllers.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:79)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method escapeXml() on null object
    at {module:testrunner}/app/views/TestRunner/results-xunit.xml.(line:23)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:232)
    ... 9 more
```

Update:
It happened because of the following exception that the test had triggered. Does the test framework supposed to blow up when a test throws an exception?

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.head(IterableLike.scala:101)
    at scala.xml.NodeSeq.head(NodeSeq.scala:43)
```